# Menu item always goes in the overflow menu in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a menu icon for my ActionBar, but it always goes into the overflow menu no matter what I do. I want it to show up as an icon and not go into the overflow menu.

Here is my menu_daily_selfie.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/camera_button"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Camera"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I'm using the appcompat library. What gives? Seems like this should work.

Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_daily_selfie, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using this menu resource from an `AppCompatActivity` subclass, or a fragment that is hosted by an `AppCompatActivity` subclass?

Comment: My main activity extends ListActivity since it uses a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main activity extends ListActivity since it uses a ListView

Then you are not using `appcompat-v7` properly. Either:

- Switch to inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`, and manage your own `ListView`, or
- Stop using `appcompat-v7`, and switch your menu resource to use `android:showAsAction` instead of `app:showAsAction`

Comment: The best thing was to start a new project with AppCompat unchecked, and copy code into that. With new layouts I was able to get it the way I wanted.